# TinyMCE editor only shows on first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, tinymce-4

This is my selector (I'm using tinyMCE 4.2.8)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
        });
    });
```

i have 1-10 textareas per page inside collapses that i want to convert to TinyMCE editors

For some reason only the first one get's transformed and the others are just normal textareas.

I'm using MVC to render the collapse as views with layout set to null

What can be wrong?

HTML code

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Huvudkategori</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Antal subkategorier</th>
                <th>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class=" col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <input id="searchString" name="searchString" class="form-control float-left" style="width: 75%" type="text" placeholder="Sök">
                                <input value="Sök" type="submit" class="btn btn-info float-left" style="width: 25%" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Categories>)ViewBag.Categorys)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.CategoryName</td>
                        <td>@item.CategoryId</td>
                        <td>@item.SubCategories.Count()</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Underkategorier", "Index", "SubCategory", new { id = item.CategoryId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                            <a class="btn btn-info" href="#@item.CategoryId" data-toggle="collapse">Detaljer</a>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Ta bort", "Delete", new { id = item.CategoryId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="collapse" id="@item.CategoryId">
                        <td colspan="4">
                            <div class="well">
                                @Html.Action("Details", new { id = item.CategoryId })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.Categorys, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast)
```

Details HTML

```
@model Admin2.Models.Categories
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Kategorier";
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("DetailsSave", "Category", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryId)

<div class="well">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName, "Kategorinamn ",
                        new { @class = "text-info-large", @style = "" })
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CategoryName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommonDescription, "Beskrivning ",
                        new { @class = "text-info-large", @style = "" })
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CommonDescription, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row padding20pxTop">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <input id="saveInfo" type="submit" value="Spara" class="btn btn-info textWhite float-right" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: In the sample code there is only one TextArea... are you getting TinyMCE on CommonDescription property?

Comment: It renders 1-10 times depending how many elements there are in the ViewBag.Categorys

I do but only the first one gets the editor, if there are more then one Category the others wont get the editor if that makes sens?

Comment: I assume `@Html.Action("Details", new { id = item.CategoryId })` is generating multiple instances of the `Details.cshtml` view you have shown which is generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes for each form control) and since you can only post back one form at a time its a little unclear what your trying to achieve with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe the issue is possibly because all "TextArea" control on your page are having same id and same name. 
So for example, if you have 10 TextArea control on your page (depending upon ViewBag.Categories), then all 10 TextArea will have same ID and name properties. 
I remember similar situation created some issues at javascript level for me in the past, it wasn't for TineMCE but still its worth giving a try.

Try to give unique ID and/ or Name properties to each of your TextArea control and see what happens!

Comment: WOW tanks man this fixed it for me!
The only thing i changed was the ID because i was not sure if you can change the name AND id, dosen't MVC lose the connection between the fields and the model variabels?

Comment: that's great to know... no, in fact MVC expects a name and ID properties to be unique for proper binding between controls and model properties especially when you use array...

Comment: Ohh ok thanks again for the answer and the second answer :)

Comment: @Nirman, That is not correct. The `id` is irrelevant to MVC, but its is relevant to html and javascript which expects that `id` attribute values be unique. And the `name` does not need to be unique (in fact the `CheckBoxFor()` method which generates 2 inputs with the same name would not work if it did)

Comment: The real problem here is that OP should have only one form, and that javascript should be used to update the values of the controls based on the table row that is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
tinymce.init({
mode : "textareas",
});
```

Update:

That was for TinyMCE 3.

Did you add any more option to your init function or is it like this ?
If so you shouldn't add comma to the last option.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
        });
    });
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "textarea"
            });
        });
```

Comment: Stil only the first one gets the editor the rest are the same
I saw this on the documentation for tinyMCE 3x but not for tinyMCE4x dose this still apply and where can you read about it?

Im so lost on the website can't find what im searching for there at all

Comment: Thank you but the results are still the same, i use tinyMCE4 if that is to any help